# how to flash phone with two roms installed accidently

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I had installed a rom without wiping data.

Help me, how to flash it please.

the phone is a lenovo p700 4.0

Thanks

Comment: How did you install it? Can you use the same process to install it again but wiping data at some point?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you flashed one rom over another without wiping data and now your phone is inoperable.

In this case all you need to do is flash the second rom again. Just make sure you wipe the data/dalvik/cache before flashing the rom again. This should net you a clean install.